# Wild vs Overactive imagination

Tags: phrase-requests, differences, phrase-meaning

In a typical scenario, where someone finds out their best friend started dating, they start fantasizing (in quite vivid and colorful details, sometimes outloud) how their friend will do bunch of daring (sometimes erotic) things with their date, etc.

Such things only happened in person's head.

Is this the case of a person having **Wild** imagination, or **Overactive** imagination? I do not quite understand the differences between these two.

Comment: Typical? Really?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"Wild imagination" (wild meaning untamed) is often used by psychologists and people discussing the creative arts to denote a faculty for imagining unconventional or unpredictable things, e.g. during an artist's creative process. It can have a positive meaning. "Overactive imagination" (overactive meaning excessively - adjectives starting 'over' are often indications of excess) can have a simpler meaning - that a person is prone to fantasy without necessarily implying great creative powers. It generally has a negative meaning and is frequently used in connection with obsessive and/or compulsive disorders. From your description I would use "overactive" for that type of thinking.

[Wild imagination](https://psychosynthesistrust.org.uk/allan-frater-wild-imagination/)

[Overactive imagination](https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/overactive)

Comment: Isn't the first link a bit too psychology related? I think the question is more about the language than psychology. Btw, the 2nd link is lost.

Comment: @Michael - isn't 'imagination' psychology-related? I stand by the four-year-old answer. 2nd link fixed.